# Formula for checking time differences

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, time

I have the following setup:

In cell `A1` the time is = 09:30

In cell `B2` the time is = 16:30

In cell `C3` I would like to display a percentage based on the following criteria:

- If `B2-A1` is less than 06:00hrs, then `30%`
- If `B2-A1` is greater than 06:00hrs and less than 12:00hrs, then `70%`
- If `B2-A1` is greater than 12:00hrs, then `100%`

Comment: Use IF() function chain (`IF(cond1, var1, IF(cond2, var2, var3))`). In your case I recommend to use `<06:00` as cond1 and `>12:00` as cond2.

Comment: @Akina are you sure `<06:00 will work as a condition ? I could not achieve this when I tried

Comment: @PeterH It's a comment, so all written is idea only, neither solution nor working code.

Comment: You might want to clarify the requirements for when the difference is exactly 6 or 12 hours.

Answer (score 1):

In **C3** enter:

```
=IF(B2-A1<TIME(6,0,0),0.3,IF(B2-A1<TIME(12,0,0),0.7,1))
```

and apply formatting:

[image]